# join to non-unique field without subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a master table that has among other fields, a currency symbol

master:

```
+----+------+--------+--------+
| id | data | values | symbol |
+----+------+--------+--------+
| 1  | asdf | asdf   | US$    |
+----+------+--------+--------+
| 2  | asdf | asdf   | U$     |
+----+------+--------+--------+
| 3  | asdf | asdf   | C$     |
+----+------+--------+--------+
| 4  | asdf | asdf   | MP     |
+----+------+--------+--------+
```

and I want to join it with a currency table to get the ISO value for it,
however I don't have the id in the first table, but the "symbol" which in the second table is not unique.

currency:

```
+----+---------+------+--------+------+
| id | country | iso  | symbol | desc |
+----+---------+------+--------+------+
| 1  | US      | USD  | US$    | asdf |
+----+---------+------+--------+------+
| 2  | US      | USD  | U$     | asdf |
+----+---------+------+--------+------+
| 3  | US      | USD  | U$     | XYZ  |
+----+---------+------+--------+------+
| 4  | CA      | asdf | C$     | asdf |
+----+---------+------+--------+------+
| 5  | MX      | asdf | MP     | asdf |
+----+---------+------+--------+------+
```

How do I join so I can get the corresponding ISO column for it?
right now I'm doing the following:

```
select m.id, 
       m.data, 
       m.values, 
       m.symbol, 
       c.iso 
       from master m
       inner join (select distinct symbol, iso from currency) c on c.symbol = m.symbol
```

However although this works how should I do it without the "distinct" or even better without a subquery as I feel this is not performing in the long run.

Comment: Your current query is logically correct and is what I would probably use myself here.

Comment: Change your schema so that the pairs are unique. One way or another, you have to do that to achieve your goal. Seems you have a schema / modelling problem to me but it's your database.

Comment: @SMor yeah, sadly I don't have the option to modify this, i understand what you say and would be my approach as well

Comment: guess you could change the subquery to: "select symbol, iso from currency group by symbol, iso", that would get rid of the "distinct", and it could be more efficient, but guesss you could just try and see.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to specify the expected result - a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are only after the `iso` column here you could use a simple subquery, such as

```
select m.id, 
       m.data, 
       m.values, 
       m.symbol, 
       (select top(1) iso from currency c where c.symbol = m.symbol) iso
       from master m;
```

This would probably be more efficient as it would avoid a distinct-sort, which is unecessary since all rows are identical; as soon as the `top` operator returns a row it's done and moves on.

Of course at a glance this looks like a *code smell* but is really because your table is not normalised.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using subquery best you can use CTE (common table expression)

```
With cte as
(
select distinct symbol as symbol, iso from currency
)
   select m.id, 
           m.data, 
           m.values, 
           m.symbol, 
           c.iso 
           from master m
           inner join cte c on c.symbol = m.symbol
```

Comment: won't this get calculated everytime as well? I mean, will it operate like a subquery in the end, right?

Comment: @Baldie47 Correct - this is no improvement. There is nothing "better" than what you have.